# C++ Vending Machine program with classes c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to build a vending machine program with 3 different classes but I am stuck on the second portion of it. Basically the first class is the snack class, which takes 3 parameters (calories, name and price.) However, the second class VendSlot, should have two members, a snack (which I presume to be the object from the first files) and the quantity of snacks. I am really struggling to understand how to process the snack object within the second class though. How exactly do I pass the first snack object into my VendSlot class so that I can increase/decrease the amount in my storage in VendSlot and then let the user buy it when I reach the third item? I can't use pointers yet but can pass by reference and I am wondering if this is an effective way? The third class will be a vending machine that will have vendSlots and will take money to buy the items. Thank you for the help and let me know if you need clarification on the project!

This is my Snack header file

```
#ifndef SNACK_CPP
#include <string>
using std::string;

class Snack
{
private: 
    string nameOfSnack;
    double snackPrice;
    int numOfCalories;

public:
    Snack(); //default constructor
    Snack(string, double, int); //overload constructor
    ~Snack(); //destructor

    //Accessor functions

    string getNameOfSnack(); //returns name of snack
    double getSnackPrice(); //returns the price of the snack
    int getNumOfCalories(); //returns number of calories of snack
};



#endif // !SNACK_CPP
```

This is my snack.cpp file with constructors

```
#include "Snack.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

Snack::Snack() //default constructor
{
    nameOfSnack = "bottled water";
    snackPrice = 1.75;
    numOfCalories = 0;
}

Snack::Snack(string name, double price, int cals)
{
    nameOfSnack = name; 
    snackPrice = price; 
    numOfCalories = cals; 

}

Snack::~Snack()
{

}

string Snack::getNameOfSnack()
{
    return nameOfSnack;
}

double Snack::getSnackPrice()
{
    return snackPrice;
}

int Snack::getNumOfCalories()
{
    return numOfCalories;
}
```

Here is my VendSlot header file

```
#ifndef VENDSLOT_CPP
#include "Snack.h"
#include <string>

class VendSlot
{
public:
    VendSlot(); //default constructor
    VendSlot(string, double); //overload constructor
    string getSnack(); //get snack name
    int getAmount(); //get amount of snacks available
    void decrementAmount(int); //function to decrease storage in vending machine by 1.
    Snack snack; //passes snack object? I am confused what this should be.
   ~VendSlot(); //destructor 

private:

    double numOfSnacks; // number of snacks
};

#endif // !VENDSLOT_CPP
```

And here is my VendSlot.cpp file which I am struggling with

```
#include "VendSlot.h"
#include "Snack.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

VendSlot::VendSlot()
{
    snack;
    numOfSnacks = 5; 
}

VendSlot::VendSlot(string Snack, double Quantity)
{
    snack = Snack;
    numOfSnacks = Quantity;
}

int VendSlot::getAmount()
{
    return numOfSnacks;
}

string VendSlot::getSnack()
{
    return snack;
}


VendSlot::~VendSlot()
{
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of the program?
That would help in trying to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Here is the a tl;dr descrip - we can't include main functions so I don't know exactly what is going to get called from the function.  "Write a class called Snack - it should have data members for snack, price, and calories. The class should have three get members. Write a class called vendSlot - it should have two data members - a Snack, and amount of that snack in the slot. It should have a default constructor to initialize the default snack object and 5 items. Class should take two parameters and use them to initialize the data members. It should have two get functions and a decrements."

Comment: `VendSlot(string, double);` this seems to be a (the?) problem. You want the slot to accept a Snack, not a string. (And `double` is not a good type to model a number of pieces; can you have -4.5 snacks?) "should have two data members - a Snack, and amount of that snack in the slot" So what exactly prevents you from implementing "a Snack"?

Comment: I guess I am just wondering - how do I implement this and pass the object from the Snack class to the VendSlot class.

Comment: It looks like Snack class would be contained by the VendSlot class right? Right now you have just `snack;`, but it should be `Snack snack;`.

Comment: You don't pass "the object *from* the Snack class". You should *have* and object *of* the Snack class.

Comment: Nevermind I see you have header separate. Yes, so VendSlot contains a Snack object. This object gets instantiated when VendSlot is instantiated by its constructor.

Comment: Ok - I updated to Snack snack; however what data type do I use with the "getSnack" constructor? It's giving me an error saying "no suitable conversion function from "Snack" to "int" exists".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you work with classes in C++, imagine them as variables that contain variables. So use them the same way as you use variables.

When you call an instance of a class (or "declare the variables") the constructor is called. There are two ways on doing this. With or without parameters:

```
Snack A("Chocolate", 12.5, 199);//This will call the constructor with parameters
Snack B;//This will call the constructor without parameters
```

So now we have two objects of the same class. To use the memebers of the objects we just use a period.

```
cout << A.getNameOfSnack() << endl;//Output: Chocolate
cout << B.getNameOfSnack() << endl;//Output: bottled water
```

Also, keep in mind that we can access to the public members only.

Moving on, creating an instace of a class as a member of other class is not different.

```
class VendSlot {
public:
    Snack snack;
    int numOfSnacks;

    VendSlot();
    VendSlot(string, double);
    ~VendSlot();
};

VendSlot::VendSlot() {
    snack = Snack();//Call the constructor to create the object
    numOfSnacks = 5;
}

VendSlot::VendSlot(string nameSnack, double Quantity) {//Notice that I changed the name of the first parameter
    snack = Snack(nameSnack, 0, 0);//Call the constructor to create the object
    numOfSnacks = Quantity;
}
```

First, you need to be sure that you are not using the name of the class as the name of a variable (that will give you errors, so be careful with that). Now, since the only data you recive in the VendSlot constructor is the name of the snack, there is no more information to send as parameter to the constructor of Snack. You can either add more parameters on the VendSlot constructor or put default values.

Since the variables `nameOfSnack`, `snackPrice` and `numOfCalories` are private members of their class we can't change their values from outside the class `Snack`.

Within the class `VendSlot` (or where you create the instance of the class) you can only call the functions `getNameOfSnack`, `getSnackPrice` and `getNumOfCalories`, which are public members of `Snack`.

So, implying that the function `VendSlot::getSnack` returns the name of the snack, the function will be as following.

```
string VendSlot::getSnack() {
    return snack.getNameOfSnack();
}
```

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the point of your program or assignment. I'm answering your question of how does the Snack class get its constructor params when it is contained within VendSlot class.

The members contained in another class get their constructor parameters from the initialization list.

Here is an example for your case of how it could be done:

```
Snack::Snack(string name, double price, int cals) :
    nameOfSnack(name), 
    snackPrice(price),
    numOfCalories(cals)   
{
}

VendSlot::VendSlot(Snack& snack, int quantity) :
    snack(snack),
    numOfSnacks(quantity)
{
}
```

Also, note using a reference is what would normally be used when passing in an entire class or struct. This also means the default `Snack` copy constructor provided by the compiler will be used unless you implement one yourself. If the class only has simple native types it should work, but to be safe you should implement it yourself.
The member `quantity` would seem to be best be an `int` type as you wouldn't have fractions of a snack being sold.

Here's the assignment operator and copy constructor defined as you'll need it.

```
Snack& Snack::operator=(const Snack& snack)
{
    this->nameOfSnack = snack.name;
    this->snackPrice = snack.price;
    this->numOfCalories = snack.cals;
}

Snack::Snack(const Snack& snack)
{
    *this = snack;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I appreciate the answer. When I updated my code with the above I do get the follow errors "E0493 no instance of overloaded fnction "VendSlot::VendSlot matches the specific type"  also it says "call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type"

Comment: Ok, accept as answer if it helps. It looks like you'll have to define the copy constructor. That's a constructor that takes a reference as the same class.

Comment: Ok. Added copy constructor and assignment operator